# how to find Tag of a parent

Tags: jquery, html

I try to add a new tag when the parent equals `LI` in some circumstances. But somehow I fail. The following Code adds a HR to all Tags. But I just want it after a `LI`.

I also tried with EQ [ `li` ] and other synthax but this example shows what I want to do.

```
$.each($("tt"), function (key, value) {
    if ($(this).parent('li')) {
        $(this).after('<hr style="color:#c00;" />');
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle of your markup?

Comment: and also you can't add hr in ul

Comment: 'tt' is a class or id? show the html

Comment: @JqueryKing `tt` is an element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check tag name of each dom element in **pure javascript** by

```
element.tagName
```

also you can check it in **jQuery** by

```
dom.prop('tagName')
```

For your case i offer you to use this code inside your if statement

```
$(this).parent().prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'li'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use tagName API in DOM to do what you need. Also .parents() searches upwards for the selector given. .parentNode can be used in the place to get the immediate parent.

```
   $.each($("tt"), function(key,value) {       
        if (this.parentNode.tagName=='li') {
                $(this).after('<hr style="color:#c00;" />');
        }   
   }
```

Comment: even you can't add hr to ul , you can only add li as direct child element.

Comment: Hi - I know thats not correct adding a hr in a li-element. But for this special purpose it works (god knows why) and seems nesessary.